# How to change my name in Xcode Blame view?

Tags: xcode, macos

Where does Xcode's Blame view read my name from? I used to use a nickname before when I set up this Mac but I want to use my real name in projects, I've changed almost every user name on my Mac to my real name, including the Mac Login, App store, even the auto-generated header comment lines in every Xcode-created source code file shows my real name, however, Xcode's Blame view still shows my nickname.

Anyone have met the same issue or have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it uses your SCM's username (so the svn user / git user).

- for svn it is the login name
- for git the username can be set with 'git config'

==> it isnt related to osx names and doesnt support nice icons

Comment: Exactly what I needed, here's the command: git config --global user.name "New Name"